# What is the difference between "find next" and "next completion match"?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde

I'm trying to understand these two KDE Standard Shortcuts so I can set them properly and their [descriptions in the documentation](https://community.kde.org/KDE_Visual_Design_Group/HIG/Keyboard_Shortcuts) aren't helpful. In what situations would "find next" be different from "next completion match"?